# Failure resolving dependency from feature to included feature

Tags: tycho

Trying to build Eclipse EMF CDO which ships with a Tycho configuration (2.7.5) and I am getting the following error for all features that include other features, but no errors for features that only include plugins.

```
[INFO] [main] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.emf.cdo.features:org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples:4.5.7-SNAPSHOT @ C:\eclipse\git\org.eclipse.emf.cdo\features\org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples-feature\pom.xml
[DEBUG] No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples.feature.feature.group 4.5.7.qualifier to org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples.installer.feature.group 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
[INFO] {osgi.os=win32, osgi.ws=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples.feature.feature.group 4.5.7.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples.feature.feature.group 4.5.7.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.cdo.examples.installer.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
```

Searched everywhere and can't seem to see this type of error.